# How to save X509AttributeCertificate to PKCS12 KeyStore

Tags: attributes, x509certificate, keystore, pkcs#12

How can I save a `X509AttributeCertificate` to PKCS12 keystore ?

Comment: I assume you have googled this; where are you having problems with the solutions you found?

Comment: Do you really want someone to answer with "yes" or "no"? If not, please improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep2.html